# JavaFx VBox children not growing past a certain size

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I been trying to create a desktop app with javafx and have been hardstuck trying to figure out why the GridPane and HBox in the VBox have been refusing to expand past a certain point in the vertical direction. I have set their `.vgrow` properties to `Priority.ALWAYS` and they still seem to not want to expand when I resize the window.

The code is shown below:

```
package display;

import java.io.File;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;

public class OxygenDisplay
{

    private String openFileName;
    private String fileContents;
    private String activeVaultPath;

    private final Stage primaryStage;
    private final Scene primaryScene;
    private final MenuBar topMenu;
    private final GridPane middleStruct;
    private final HBox bottomOptions;

    public OxygenDisplay(String fileName, String fileContents, String path)
    {
        this.openFileName = fileName;
        this.fileContents = fileContents;
        this.activeVaultPath = path;

        // Create node structure for menu bar
        this.topMenu = this.generateTopMenuBar();

        // Create node structure for vault display and text editor
        this.middleStruct = this.generateMiddleStructure();

        // Create node structure for lower options bar
        this.bottomOptions = this.generateBottomOptions();

        // Post view to user
        VBox root = new VBox();
        for (Node child: root.getChildren())
        {
            VBox.setVgrow(child, Priority.ALWAYS);
        }
        root.getChildren().addAll(
                this.topMenu,
                this.middleStruct,
                this.bottomOptions
        );
        this.primaryScene = new Scene(root, 400, 300);
        this.primaryStage = new Stage();

        // Init all listeners
        this.initListeners();

        this.primaryStage.setTitle("Oxygen");
        this.primaryStage.setScene(primaryScene);
        this.primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void initListeners()
    {
        // Add window height and width listeners
        this.primaryStage.widthProperty().addListener((obsv, oldv, newv) ->
        {
//            this.mdEditor.prefWidth(newv.doubleValue());
//            this.mdEditor.maxWidth(newv.doubleValue());
        });
        this.primaryStage.heightProperty().addListener((obsv, oldv, newv) ->
        {
//            this.mdEditor.prefHeight(newv.doubleValue());
//            this.mdEditor.maxHeight(newv.doubleValue());
        });
    }

    public String getOpenFileName()
    {
        return this.openFileName;
    }

    public void setOpenFileName(String file)
    {
        this.openFileName = file;
    }

    public String getFileContents()
    {
        return this.fileContents;
    }

    public void setFileContents(String data)
    {
        this.fileContents = data;
    }

    private MenuBar generateTopMenuBar()
    {
        MenuBar topBar = new MenuBar();
        Menu file = new Menu("File");
        Menu edit = new Menu("Edit");
        Menu view = new Menu("View");
        Menu help = new Menu("Help");
        SeparatorMenuItem fileSeparator = new SeparatorMenuItem();
        SeparatorMenuItem editSeparator = new SeparatorMenuItem();


        // TODO: Add event handlers for these options
        MenuItem open = new MenuItem("Open");
        MenuItem newNote = new MenuItem("New Note");
        MenuItem newVault = new MenuItem("New Vault");
        MenuItem save = new MenuItem("Save");
        MenuItem saveAs = new MenuItem("Save as");
        file.getItems().addAll(
                open,
                newNote,
                newVault,
                fileSeparator,
                save,
                saveAs
        );

        // TODO: Add event handlers for these options
        MenuItem copy = new MenuItem("Copy");
        MenuItem paste = new MenuItem("Paste");
        MenuItem cut = new MenuItem("Cut");
        MenuItem find = new MenuItem("Find");
        edit.getItems().addAll(
                cut,
                copy,
                paste,
                editSeparator,
                find
        );

        // TODO: Add event handlers for these options
        MenuItem appearance = new MenuItem("Appearance");
        view.getItems().addAll(
                appearance
        );

        // TODO: Add event handlers for these options
        MenuItem about = new MenuItem("About");
        help.getItems().addAll(
                about
        );

        topBar.getMenus().addAll(
                file,
                edit,
                view,
                help
        );

        return topBar;
    }

    private void generateFileStructure(File node, TreeItem<String> root)
    {
        // TODO: Order the tree structure so that files are always before
        //  directories. Currently it is based on file names.
        if (node.isDirectory())
        {
            TreeItem<String> item = new TreeItem<>(node.getName());
            root.getChildren().add(item);
            for (File f: node.listFiles())
            {
                TreeItem<String> temp = new TreeItem<>();
                item.getChildren().add(temp);

                // When parent is expanded continue the recursion
                item.addEventHandler(TreeItem.branchExpandedEvent(),
                new EventHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(Event event)
                    {
                        generateFileStructure(f, item);
                        item.getChildren().remove(temp);
                        item.removeEventHandler(TreeItem.branchExpandedEvent(),
                                this);
                    }
                });
            }
        } else
        {
            root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(node.getName()));
        }
    }

    private TreeView<String> generateVaultStructure()
    {

        File fileInputDirLocation = new File(this.activeVaultPath);
        File[] fileList = fileInputDirLocation.listFiles();
        TreeView<String> vaultStruct = new TreeView<>();
        TreeItem<String> root =
                new TreeItem<>(fileInputDirLocation.getAbsoluteFile().getName());

        // create tree
        assert fileList != null;
        for (File file: fileList)
        {
            this.generateFileStructure(file, root);
        }

        vaultStruct.setRoot(root);

        return vaultStruct;
    }

    private GridPane generateMiddleStructure()
    {
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        TreeView<String> vaultStruct = this.generateVaultStructure();
        TextArea mdEditor = new TextArea();
        mdEditor.setText(this.fileContents);

        gridPane.add(vaultStruct, 0, 0);
        gridPane.add(mdEditor, 1, 0);

        // For resizing purposes
        GridPane.setHgrow(vaultStruct, Priority.NEVER);
        GridPane.setHgrow(mdEditor, Priority.ALWAYS);

        GridPane.setVgrow(vaultStruct, Priority.ALWAYS);
        GridPane.setVgrow(mdEditor, Priority.ALWAYS);

        return gridPane;
    }

    private HBox generateBottomOptions()
    {
        HBox bottomOptions = new HBox();
        Label openFileDisplay = new Label("");
        openFileDisplay.textProperty().bind(
                new SimpleStringProperty(this.openFileName)
        );

        bottomOptions.getChildren().addAll(
                openFileDisplay
        );

        // For resizing purposes
        HBox.setHgrow(bottomOptions, Priority.ALWAYS);

        return bottomOptions;
    }
}
```

Example image:
[The red area is what I need to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H14F4.png)

Any help is appreciated in finding out why this is occuring? Let me know if anyone wants to run the above code as it requires a seperate class that extends Application for javafx.

Comment: “Let me know if anyone wants to run the below code” -> No.  I mean not the current code, but yes for modified code. If you would like the best chance of getting useful assistance, what you need to do is edit the question and provide a [mcve], a complete program that replicates the issue and *only* the issue and can be run by copy and paste with no modification or addition. No files, no tree views, no menus, those things have nothing to do with your question and only serve to confuse and make it more difficult to answer.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was the order of the for loop which gave all children process `Priority.ALWAYS`:

**Old**:

```
// Post view to user
        VBox root = new VBox();
        for (Node child: root.getChildren())
        {
            VBox.setVgrow(child, Priority.ALWAYS);
        }
        root.getChildren().addAll(
                this.topMenu,
                this.middleStruct,
                this.bottomOptions
        );
```

**New**:

```
// Post view to user
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        root.getChildren().addAll(
                this.topMenu,
                this.middleStruct,
                this.bottomOptions
        );
        for (Node child: root.getChildren())
        {
            VBox.setVgrow(child, Priority.ALWAYS);
        }
```

Although now the GridPane and Label/HBox expand together due to both of the panes having `Priority.ALWAYS`. Hence, to overcome this is to give GridPane maximum priority.

**New Version 2**:

```
        // Post view to user
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        root.getChildren().addAll(
                this.topMenu,
                this.middleStruct,
                this.bottomOptions
        );
        VBox.setVgrow(this.middleStruct, Priority.ALWAYS);
        VBox.setVgrow(this.bottomOptions, Priority.NEVER);
```

Cheers.